# How to typecast this class?

Tags: java, class, oop, object, inheritance

I have this super class called BasketBallPlayer

I have a child class called ProBasketBallPlayer

If I create an object

```
BasketBallPlayer bp1;
bp1=new BasketBallPlayer("Tim Duncan", "Center", "Spurs", 83, 220, 4, 5, 8);


public class BasketBallPlayer {
    protected String name;
    protected String position;
    protected String team;
    protected int height;
    protected int weight;
    protected int agility;
    protected int speed;
    protected int ballHandling;

    public BasketBallPlayer() {
        this.name = "unknown";
        this.position = "unknown";
        this.team = "unknown";
        this.height = 0;
        this.weight = 0;
        this.agility = 0;
        this.speed = 0;
        this.ballHandling = 0;
    }

    public BasketBallPlayer( String name, String position, String team)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.position = position;
        this.team = team;
        this.height = 0;
        this.weight = 0;
        this.agility = 0;
        this.speed = 0;
        this.ballHandling = 0;
    }

    public BasketBallPlayer (String name, String position, String team, int height, int weight,
                int agility, int speed, int ballHandling)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.position = position;
        this.team = team;
        this.height = height;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.agility = agility;
        this.speed = speed;
        this.ballHandling = ballHandling;
    }
```

How can I typecast it to ProBasketballPlayer without getting ClassCastException

Here are the ProBasketballPlayer constructors

```
public class ProBasketballPlayer extends BasketBallPlayer {
    protected int yearsInLeague;
    protected String role;

    public ProBasketballPlayer()
    {
        super();
        yearsInLeague = 0;
        role = "bench";
    }

    public ProBasketballPlayer( String name, String position, String team )
    {
        super(name, position, team);
        this.name = name;
        this.position = position;
        this.team = team;
        yearsInLeague = 0;
        role = "bench";
    }

    public ProBasketballPlayer(String name, String position, String team, int height, int weight,
            int agility, int speed, int ballHandling, int yearsInLeague, String role)
    {
        super(name, position, team, height, weight, agility, speed, ballHandling);
        this.yearsInLeague = yearsInLeague;
        this.role = role;
    }
```

Comment: You can only cast a subclass as its superclass, not the other way round. To put it simply, a Ferrari is a type of car, but a car is not a type of Ferrari. I could create a List<Car> and add Mercedes, Ferrari and Ford cars to the list and it'd be quite happy given that each of these subclasses have a superclass of Car.

Comment: You should put your Tim Duncan on a diet. Weighing 220 pounds at a height of 83 centimeters doesn’t sound healthy.

Comment: @RolandIllig Something tells me it's inches... XD

Comment: @4castle: thanks for the explanation. — So this program should only be maintained by Americans, not by metric Europeans. Because to them, it might look like the height (220 cm) and weight (83 kg) were mixed up, resulting in a huge but very thin player.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. Casting doesn't change anything about an object, it just tells the compiler that it can interpret the object as a class that is further *up* the class hierarchy, but not down. Once you instantiate an object, that's it - that object is definitely and irrevocably a member of the class you instantiated. It is a `BasketballPlayer`, and never will be a `ProBasketballPlayer`. If you want a Pro, instantiate one - you'll be able to use the Pro as a normal Basketball player, but not vice versa.

As an example:

```
class Foo
{
    int a;
}
class Bar extends Foo
{
    int b;
}

Foo obj = new Foo();
obj.a = 0; // our obj has an "a" field because it is a Foo.
obj.b = 0; // but no "b" field, because it is not a Bar.

// It therefore makes no sense to do this:
((Bar)obj).b = 0; // because that's the same as trying to do "obj.b"

// in either case, "obj" is not a "Bar", and cannot have a "b" field. "obj" will always be a "Foo", never a "Bar".

//
// If however we make a Bar:
Bar obj2 = new Bar();

// we can access both fields, since Bar has both of them
obj2.a = 0;
obj2.b = 0;

// and, since Bar is a SUPERSET of Foo (all Bar are Foo, not all Foo are Bar), 
// we can even use obj2 as a Foo, and pass it to methods which accept a Foo.
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I typecast it to ProBasketballPlayer without getting
>   ClassCastException

You can't cast in the wrong direction. Think about the following two statements...

1. **`ISA`** BasketballPlayer a ProBasketballPlayer?
2. Are **all** BasketBallPlayers ProBasketBall players?

No. I play basketball and I'm not a pro basketball player.

Is every `Bird` a `Duck`.

```
Bird b = new Bird();
Duck daffy = (Bird)b;
daffy.quack(); // Error here, not all birds quack?
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't cast an object to a subclass. Objects can only be casted "downward" from what their constructor's type was. Every `Cat` is an `Animal`, but not every `Animal` is a `Cat`. Casting only goes one way.

What you **can** do is create a constructor in `ProBasketballPlayer` that accepts a `BasketBallPlayer` and copies in the relevant fields. Make sure to initialize any additional fields that `ProBasketballPlayer` may have also.

```
public ProBasketballPlayer(BasketBallPlayer bbp, int yearsInLeague, String role) {
    super(bbp.getName(), bbp.getPosition(), bbp.getTeam(), bbp.getHeight(), bbp.getWeight(), bbp.getAgility(), bbp.getSpeed(), bbp.getBallHandling());
    this.yearsInLeague = yearsInLeague;
    this.role = role;
}

public public ProBasketballPlayer(BasketBallPlayer bbp) {
    this(bbp, 0, "bench");
}
```

If `ProBasketballPlayer` is in the same package as `BasketBallPlayer`, then you can access the fields directly (e.g. `bbp.name`) instead of using getters.

Comment: Ok I like the sound of that, but how do I make a a constructor that accepts something like that inside of ProBasketballplayer?

Comment: Updated my answer. You will have to make getters for all of the instance data in `BasketBallPlayer`, or else `protected` would keep you from accessing the data. If you can't add getters, it may be impossible.

Comment: Unless they are in the same package, I should mention.